# How to add a title to a html select tag

Tags: html

How would I go about setting a title in select tag? Here is my select box:

```
<select>
    <option value="sydney">Sydney</option>
    <option value="melbourne">Melbourne</option>
    <option value="cromwell">Cromwell</option>
    <option value="queenstown">Queenstown</option>
</select>
```

When I visit the site, by default it shows "Sydney". But I want to display a title, such as, "What is the name of your city?"

Answer (score 162, accepted):

```
<select>
    <option selected disabled>Choose one</option>
    <option value="sydney">Sydney</option>
    <option value="melbourne">Melbourne</option>
    <option value="cromwell">Cromwell</option>
    <option value="queenstown">Queenstown</option>
</select>
```

Using `selected` and `disabled` will make "Choose one" be the default selected value, but also make it impossible for the user to actually select the item, like so:

[image: Dropdown menu]

Comment: It's never impossible to submit user input (or modify a client-side field).

Comment: Yes, of course, the users can do whatever they want, and submit completely unrelated values, but let's not turn this into a debate about data sanitation. All I'm saying is that the user can't select "Choose one". This is a usability feature, not a security feature.

Comment: What if the user submits the `select` form without even touching the `options`? Wouldn't that submit the `disabled` field?

Answer (score 42):

```
<select>
    <optgroup label = "Choose One">
    <option value ="sydney">Sydney</option>
    <option value ="melbourne">Melbourne</option>
    <option value ="cromwell">Cromwell</option>
    <option value ="queenstown">Queenstown</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: You can not rely on a browser displaying the optgroup label in the select box initially, which is what the OP wants.

Answer (score 30):

You can combine it with selected and hidden

```
<select class="dropdown" style="width: 150px; height: 26px">
        <option selected hidden>What is your name?</option>
        <option value="michel">Michel</option>
        <option value="thiago">Thiago</option>
        <option value="Jonson">Jonson</option>
</select>
```

Your dropdown title will be selected and cannot chose by the user.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the following

```
<select data-hai="whatup">
      <option label="Select your city">Select your city</option>
      <option value="sydney">Sydney</option>
      <option value="melbourne">Melbourne</option>
      <option value="cromwell">Cromwell</option>
      <option value="queenstown">Queenstown</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 8):

I think that this would help:

```
<select name="select_1">
    <optgroup label="First optgroup category">
      <option selected="selected" value="0">Select element</option>
      <option value="2">Option 1</option>
      <option value="3">Option 2</option>
      <option value="4">Option 3</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Second optgroup category">
      <option value="5">Option 4</option>
      <option value="6">Option 5</option>
      <option value="7">Option 6</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: why will it help?

Comment: This looks like a copy/paste of b3tac0d3's solution.  I don't see anything of value added?

Answer (score 5):

```
<option value="" selected style="display:none">Please select one item</option>
```

Using `selected` and using `display: none;`  for hidden item in list.

Answer (score 2):

You can add an `option` tag on top of the others with no value and a prompt like this:

```
<select>
        <option value="">Choose One</option>
        <option value ="sydney">Sydney</option>
        <option value ="melbourne">Melbourne</option>
        <option value ="cromwell">Cromwell</option>
        <option value ="queenstown">Queenstown</option>
</select>
```

Or leave it blank instead of saying Choose one if you want.

Comment: I thought your answer was correct *without* the `value` attribute.  Why add it in?

Comment: @BLaZuRE I was under the impression that the option tags required a value tag. I had forgot to put it in initially. Can you leave it out?

Comment: When value is not specified, some browsers (which, maybe, don't deserve the name of 'browser', but it's another debate ;) ) use the title ("Choose one") as the value. So better add explicitly a value="".

Answer (score 2):

Typically, I would suggest that you use the [**`<optgroup>`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/optgroup) option, as that gives some nice styling and indenting to the element.

> The HTML  element creates a grouping of options within a  element. (Source: [**MDN Web Docs: `<optgroup>`**.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/optgroup)

But, since an `<optgroup>` cannot be a selected value, you can make an `<option selected disabled>` and then stylize it with CSS so that it behaves like an `<optgroup>`....

```css
.optionGroup {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<select>
    <option class="optionGroup" selected disabled>Choose one</option>
    <option value="sydney" class="optionChild">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Sydney</option>
    <option value="melbourne" class="optionChild">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Melbourne</option>
    <option value="cromwell" class="optionChild">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Cromwell</option>
    <option value="queenstown" class="optionChild">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Queenstown</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

The first option's text will always display as default title.

```
   <select>
        <option value ="">What is the name of your city?</option>
        <option value ="sydney">Sydney</option>
        <option value ="melbourne">Melbourne</option>
        <option value ="cromwell">Cromwell</option>
        <option value ="queenstown">Queenstown</option>
   </select>
```

Comment: As far as I can remember this is not true. Firefox used to "remember" last selected position in a dropdown, so imho you shouldn't rely on first option being always selected by default.

Answer (score 0):

With a default option having selected attribute

```
<select>
        <option value="" selected>Choose your city</option>
        <option value ="sydney">Sydney</option>
        <option value ="melbourne">Melbourne</option>
        <option value ="cromwell">Cromwell</option>
        <option value ="queenstown">Queenstown</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create **dropdown title | label** with selected, hidden and style for old or unsupported device.

```
<select name="city" >
<option selected hidden style="display:none">What is your city</option>
   <option value="1">Sydney</option>
   <option value="2">Melbourne</option>
   <option value="3">Cromwell</option>
   <option value="4">Queenstown</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I added a `<div>` and it worked fine

```html
<div title="Your title here!">
    <select>
        <option value="sydney">Sydney</option>
        <option value="melbourne">Melbourne</option>
        <option value="cromwell">Cromwell</option>
        <option value="queenstown">Queenstown</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: That's not what OP is asking for.

Answer (score 0):

The option disabled

```
<select id="county">
  <option value='japan' disabled>Japan</option>
  <option value='india'> India</option>
  <option value='kuwait'> Kuwait</option>
  <option value='Malaysia'> Malaysia</option>
  <option value='maldives'> Maldives</option>
</select>
```

Comment: While your answer is not wrong, it does not explain how or why to do it this way. Take a look at the accepted answer and see how much detail they put in.

Answer (score -2):

```
<select name="city">
   <option value ="0">What is your city</option>
   <option value ="1">Sydney</option>
   <option value ="2">Melbourne</option>
   <option value ="3">Cromwell</option>
   <option value ="4">Queenstown</option>
</select>
```

You can use the unique id for the value instead