# HTML title for dropdown list

Tags: html, title

Hi can seem to find the solution for this one, so any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance...

simply put...

```
<select id="direction" title="Please choose a direction">
  <option value="le">Left</option>
  <option selected value="st">Striat</option>
  <option value="ri">Right</option>
</select>
```

a simple dropdown, but the title whilst the mouse is over, doesnt show?

am i being a plank?
any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add a title in html select tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18179960/how-to-add-a-title-in-html-select-tag)

Comment: `The title attribute can be spoken by screen readers or displayed as a tool tip for people using screen magnifiers.` - http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H65

Comment: Are you trying to get the tool tip to show "please choose a direction" or wanting it to show as place holder text?

Comment: what browser are you using? I get a title to show in chrome using your exact code:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/sxHpB

Comment: hi, thanks for replies,, no its not duplicate as the other question is about selecting the option as a title. in my example i have not put it as an option as it will increase the width of the dropdown. im guessing a tool tip is what i want???? im using ie 11, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thanks for replies.
I found a away by putting it in a div and giving the div a title...

```
<div title="select number">
    <select id="select">
        <option>one</option>
        <option>two</option>
        <option>three</option>
    </select>
</div>
```