# How to display text on the option bar, but not as an option in HTML.

Tags: html

I have looked around for a while now and could not find anything. The thing I want to do is to have a dropdown menu and have a default title on it, but when you press the option it will change it to that (which it already does). I have this basic code here:

```
    <select>
        <option>Choose Color</option>
        <option value="red">Option 1</option>
        <option value="green">Option 2</option>
        <option value="blue">Option 3</option>
    </select>
```

So here I have 4 options. However I only want 3 (because at the moment "Choose Color" is an option which I do not want) and I want the "Choose Color" just to be a title for if nothing is selected (or default). - Thanks

Comment: You can use [`optgroup`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/optgroup)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add a title to a html select tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18179960/how-to-add-a-title-to-a-html-select-tag)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this trick:

```
<select>
    <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled" value="" style="display: none;">Select your option</option>
    <option value="red">Option 1</option>
    <option value="green">Option 2</option>
    <option value="blue">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

Improved answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805059/select-placeholder#answer-5859221).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```html
<select>
    <option style="display: none;">Choose Color</option>
    <option value="red">Option 1</option>
    <option value="green">Option 2</option>
    <option value="blue">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Ahh yes, it is much more compact. Thanks