# HTML Select Option Title not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I have recently upgraded my Chrome browser version

[image]

In this version i have tried the below code and ***when i hover the option it does not display the tooltip***.

```
<select title="Rejection Codes">
<option title="Desk">SDE</option>
<option title="Live">TOP</option>
<option title="OnShore">ERT</option>
</select>
```

Any one please advise how to achieve this in this chrome version

**Note:** I have googled this thing and most of them faced this issue and from that tickets i didn't get any solution. I saw that tickets were open with some discussion.

Comment: Pretty sure `title` is not supported:  

See: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18179960/how-to-add-a-title-to-a-html-select-tag][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18179960/how-to-add-a-title-to-a-html-select-tag

Comment: @macinnir : Yes i saw that discussion and mine is different. i need a tooltip on each of the items. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Using Chrome Version: Version 43.0.2357.81 (64-bit) (note - without the "m").

This fiddle shows tooltips for every item in the select box for me: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/479qhvyq/)

Comment: Looks like a fix will be forthcoming:
[https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=491223](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=491223)

Answer (score 2):

I've tried the Fiddle mentioned and found that it doesn't work with Chrome version Version 43.0.2357.124 m but it does work with IE11 Version 11.0.9600.17843.

This used to work with an earlier version of Chrome.