# HTML title "hint" of a <option> in a <select> not showing on mac OS chrome browser

Tags: html, macos

I am having an issue with making the title "hint" not showing on a dropdown option. This only happens on mac OS with Google chrome.

Is there any work arounds for this issue?

Code Snippet / Example:

```html
<select>
  <option title="hint for example 1">Example 1</option>
  <option title="hint for example 2">Example 2</option>
  <option title="hint for example 3">Example 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: The hint is showing up for me on Chrome on Mac. Your title and description are a little confusing. The titles says it's not showing but your description sounds like it is showing and you don't want it too?

Comment: Does this help you understand the problem? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30658216/html-select-option-title-not-working-in-chrome

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option I don't see a title attribute? What is expected variable