# How to show two items in a dropdown box, the unselectable default and the first selectable item?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

Using HTML and CSS, how can I make a dropdown menu which, without being hovered over or clicked, shows two items, namely the unselectable default (title) and the first selectable item?

At the moment all I have got this, which shows the title item only:

**HTML**

```
<select class="select-box" id="form" onChange="window.location.href=this.value">
<option value="">Select</option>
<option value="http://foobar.com/1.html">1</option>
<option value="http://foobar.com/2.html">2</option>
<option value="http://foobar.com/3.html">3</option>
<option value="http://foobar.com/4.html">4</option>
</select>
```

**CSS**

```
.select-box {border:1px solid #000; height:18px; text-align: center; }
form input[type="text"] {
    height: 14px; width: 200px;
    margin-top: 3px; color: #000; border: 1px solid #000; }
```

Comment: Are you after some thing like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18179960/how-to-add-a-title-to-a-html-select-tag

Comment: If you mean the suggestion in the top answer there, that gives the same as I've already got. I need two items to be showing, the unselectable default and the first selectable item. At the moment only the unselectable default shows.

Comment: See answer from ovokuro. Basically the size option, tells how many options you want to show!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `size` attribute in your `select` element. Also, remove the `height` property for this to work.

```css
.select-box {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
}

form input[type="text"] {
  height: 14px;
  width: 200px;
  margin-top: 3px;
  color: #000;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<select class="select-box" id="form" onChange="window.location.href=this.value" size="2">
<option value="">Select</option>
<option value="http://foobar.com/1.html">1</option>
<option value="http://foobar.com/2.html">2</option>
<option value="http://foobar.com/3.html">3</option>
<option value="http://foobar.com/4.html">4</option>
</select> CSS
```