# How do you properly label a dropdown menu used to fill in a sentence?

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria

I have a set of radio buttons to choose the frequency of an event, one of which is as follows:

```
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="mondayMonthly" id="mondayMonthly">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="mondayMonthly">
            <select class="form-control-inline" id="mondayMonthlyNumber" name="mondayMonthlyNumber">
                <option>1st</option>
                <option>2nd</option>
                <option>3rd</option>
                <option>4th</option>
                <option>5th</option>
            </select>
              Monday of the month</label>
 </div>
```

Result:
[image: Image: output of above code - a radio button with a label reading "2nd Monday of the month". "2nd" is a dropdown menu.]

The flow for interacting with this is as follows:

1. Select a radio item.
2. In the radio button's label, choose whether the event happens on the 1st, 2nd, 3rd… Monday of the month.

What's the best way to mark this up for accessibility? I'm thinking there's some version of the `aria-` attributes and maybe `for=""` that would make this work, but I really don't know where to start.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, there are multiple approaches. My preferred one (as it ALWAYS works for both braille display and voice, on Windows and Apple's OS):

```
<label id="selectorLabel">Just for demo purposes...</label>
<select aria-labeledby="selectorLabel" name="demoSelector">
<option value="foo">Foo</option>
<option value="bar">Bar</option>
</select>
```

Other ways are using for (here you need the id on the dropdown while the for property is on the label). Or you can do what the other solution suggested.

Advantage of `aria-labeledby`? The name of the selector appears next to EACH option, as opposed to just being one (disabled) option. At least on Windows. On Apple's OS, the label appears next to the drop down, and once activated, the options appear at the bottom of the page. I personally dislike the for property, as it's not properly processed by braille displays on Apple's OS, leaving the element "unlabeled" for braille display users -- although it IS labeled.

Comment: It seems you did quite some testing, awesome. I'm a bit confused, though, since the basic rule of aria is to NOT use it if there's an HTML way to do things. Is wrapping the input in the label also an issue for the braille displays?

Comment: "The name of the selector appears next to EACH option" seems like a personal preference to me, and I would say one should stick to the AT designers' decision, especially with such a basic feature.

Comment: I am deafblind myself, so the "testing" happens while I live :-) As for "No ARIA is better than bad ARIA" and similar rules - this is not bad ARIA. I think the rule applies more to using the <button> element instead of <span role="button"> or something like that.

Comment: @Andy As for wrapping it in a label, I don't think that's an issue. I just don't do it, but that's a personal preference thingy again. Whether or not it has any negative side-effects you'd have to test with a braille display. For voice only: No, certainly no accessibility issues there.

Comment: Funny twist: For mouse users, clicking the `<label>` will focus the `<select>`, which makes the whole pair easier to hit. `aria-labelledby` doesn't support that. It's not the same semantic.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the select tag display a default title such as "Which Monday of the month would you prefer?", by adding an option tag at the first position, and giving it the "selected" and "disabled" attributes. The "selected" attribute makes it such that the option tag (with the selected attribute) is preselected when the page loads, and the disabled attribute so that the user cannot actually select that option tag.

Check out the first answer here: [How to add a title to a html select tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18179960/how-to-add-a-title-to-a-html-select-tag)

Comment: The [title attribute has a number of accessibility issues](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/title#Accessibility_concerns) and should not be relied upon to convey important information.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there will be more than one group of radio/select, I'd mark that up like this:

```
<fieldset class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <legend>Choose frequency</legend>
  <p>
    <input class="form-check-input" aria-label="monday monthly" type="radio" name="mondayMonthly">
    <select class="form-control-inline" aria-label="which monday of the month">
      <option aria-label="first">1st</option>
      <option aria-label="second">2nd</option>
      <option aria-label="third">3rd</option>
      <option aria-label="forth">4th</option>
      <option aria-label="fifth">5th</option>
    </select>
    <span>Monday of the month</span>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input class="form-check-input" aria-label="tuesday monthly" type="radio" name="mondayMonthly">
    <select class="form-control-inline" aria-label="which tuesday of the month">
      <option aria-label="first">1st</option>
      <option aria-label="second">2nd</option>
      <option aria-label="third">3rd</option>
      <option aria-label="forth">4th</option>
      <option aria-label="fifth">5th</option>
    </select>
    <span>Tuesday of the month</span>
  </p>
  <p>
    ...
  </p>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: The aria-labels with first, second etc. aren't necessary as all screenreaders I tested (JAWS, NVDA, VoiceOver) turn "1st" into "first" automatically. Plus there's a potential issue: The accessible name and content does not match. If a blind user presses "t" to jump to third, this won't works as the content is actually 3rd.